# Capture Stored Procedure print output in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures

Is it possible to capture print output from a T-SQL stored procedure in .NET?

I have a lot of legacy procs that use the print as means of errorMessaging.  An example, is it possible to access the outprint 'word' from following PROC?

```sql
-- The PROC
CREATE PROC usp_PrintWord AS
    PRINT 'word'
```

```cs
// Some C# Code to would like to pull out 'word'
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_printWord", TheConnection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
// string ProcPrint = ???
```

Comment: It maybe not only about errors. I will try to use this to keep track of progress of a long running stored proc by watching the informative output.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can do this by adding an event handler to the [InfoMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) event on the connection.

```
 myConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(myConnection_InfoMessage);

    void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
```

Comment: If you also want the rows affected count then you need a handler for the StatementCompleted event on the SqlCommand.

Comment: @Nicholas can you elaborate? I can't get that event to work properly. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993049/retrieve-record-counts-from-multiple-statements

Comment: Are you catching all messages produced within sql server with that event ? Is it possible that this event will also catch some other messages, not produced by that stored procedure ?

Comment: This may be obvious but if there is no output from the proc (no print, raiseerror, etc.) then the event is not triggered.  This stumped me for a while until I realized what was happening.

Comment: @FrenkyB I can confirm that it will capture all output (print, raiserror, etc.) from the invoked proc or any procs or functions which it calls.

Answer (score 11):

This is really handy if you want to capture Print output in LinqPad's output console:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
//anonymous function to dump print statements to output console
conn.InfoMessage += (object obj, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)=>{
                e.Message.Dump();
            };
```

Comment: Where does `.Dump()` come from? Is this a custom extension method?

Comment: @ˈvɔlə - Yes, this is a LinqPad extension method that dumps data to the results pane.

Answer (score 6):

To get the output into a variable:

```
string printOutput = "";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    // handle this event to receive the print output
    conn.InfoMessage += (object obj, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e) => {
        printOutput += e.Message;
    };

    // 
    // execute command, etc. here
    // 
}

Console.Write(printOutput);
```

Comment: i like compactness of this