# Entity C# Store Procedure set to return an int, but I want the print statement in the proc...Is this possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

The DBAs wrote the proc with a print statement.  Other parts of the code can use this no problem.  But now we are encouraged to use entity queries against the database.

The only return on the proc is an int of how many rows were changed.  In the store procedure is a Print statement of the results.  Is it possible to use entity in a way to grab that print statement as the proc executes?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible uplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401874/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net-different-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401874/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net-different-model)?

Comment: seems like the correct route.  I'm having trouble with it (maybe experience with entity and sql in general).  I'll play around a bit with it though to see if I can fumble through it.