# Get an error message from TSQL output clause with SqlDataReader

Tags: t-sql, ado.net, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I have the following SQL

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table1] ([val1], [val2]) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.* 
VALUES (@val1, @val2)
```

I use `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` to get a `SqlDataReader` that reads the outputed row. It all works fine when the parameters are correct.

The problems begin when the table has a constraint not met by the parameters, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table1]
ADD CONSTRAINT [chk_table1_distinct_values] 
CHECK (val1 <> val2)
```

If I execute the command with the the same value for val1 and val2 the reader fails silently. All I can do is to check the `SqlDataReader.HasRows` property, that returns `false`.

So my question is how can I get a more specific error from the returned `SqlDataReader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you inspected the "normal" output like in [Capture Stored Procedure print output in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net)

copied from AdaTheDev:

```
myConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(myConnection_InfoMessage);
void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with e.Message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `begin try..catch` and within the `catch` section, `raiserror`.

Comment: Can this be executed as SqlCommand.CommandText = "TRY ... CATCH .." and ExecuteReader()? Smells more like a stored procedure...

Comment: No. what I meant was to implement using T-SQL and raiserror from sproc and you can get an error message from C# exception.