# C# get stored procedure printed text

Tags: c#, t-sql

I'm having a stored procedure that returns printed text. E.g

To import this report into Excel (and preserve leading zeros in numbers, etc):

1. Click here, then press CTRL-A, CTRL-C.
2. Open Excel, press CTRL-A, right-click mouse, select Format Cells, click Text.
3. Click on A1 cell, press SHIFT-INS to paste.

REPORT FOR 21-09-2013

Date        Who             Total
21-09-2013      ALBERT              10

So i want to be able to retrieve this text from my C# application. I've tried to retrieve it via ExecuteScalar() and ExecuteReader() but no luck. Is there any other alternative to solve this problem ?

Comment: How does that SP returns printed text? Does it run SELECT statement or simple uses PRINT at the end?

Comment: If the later - take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1880507/961695

Comment: @Yuriy It loops through a CURSOR. Inside the while loop it prints values.

Comment: This link(stackoverflow.com/a/1880507/961695) helped. Thanks Yuriy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture Stored Procedure print output in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net)