# How do I get the output from Database.ExecuteNonQuery?

Tags: c#, command, output, capture, executenonquery

I would like to use the Database.ExecuteNonQuery or something similar to execute a sql script and then capture the output.

eg: xxx Table created

My script:

```
        strArray = Regex.Split(streamReader.ReadToEnd(), "\r\nGO");
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd;
            foreach (string sql in strArray)
            {
                cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql);
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                Console.WriteLine(sql);
                Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: use execute instead of executenonquery

Comment: executenonquery returns an int of `The number of rows affected.`

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of affected records not the result of a query that returns something. Therefore use `ExecuteScalar`.

Answer (score 11):

If I understand correctly, I think you mean to retrieve the "informational messages" that come from issuing a sql command. I have not tried, but I think the "print statements" results are handled the same way. In which case, you need to add a informational event handler to your sql connection object.

See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net) which explains how to do this.

Pretty simple (snippet grabbed from aticle)

```
myConnection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(myConnection_InfoMessage);

void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    myStringBuilderDefinedAsClassVariable.AppendLine(e.Message);
}
```

Comment: I have multiple sql commands to execute, so i want a log file with sql command that get executed followed by its output.  eg: sql command #1.. output #1...... sql command #2.. output #2

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteNonQuery` return an `int` based on the number of rows affected and is used for `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT`.

See the MSDN documentation

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You want `ExecuteScalar`