# mysql load data local show warning from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I wrote a simple program to load a csv file using `LOAD DATA LOCAL..`

```
     loadFileSQL = "LOAD DATA...."
     using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(loadFileSQL, conn))
           {
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Loading File....");
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        Console.WriteLine("Load file complete...");

                    }
                    catch (MySqlException ex)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("MySQL Something went wrong" + ex.InnerException.Message);
                    }

                    ...
            }
```

I would like to log the message how many rows were inserted, how many skipped and how many failed..How do i capture that ? If some failed, is it possible to know which rows failed?

Comment: Use `cmd.ExecuteScalar` to get number of affected rows. You will get only number, no details

Comment: Yes, but what about how many skipped failed..etc similar to what you see when you execute the  load data on a mysql command prompt

Comment: You can try to write an event handler for the MySqlConnection.InfoMessage event. I don't know if it works in your context but worth a try. _InfoMessage(object sender, MySqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)_ then look at the errors collection of MySqlError.

Comment: in this case you probably want to execute queries one by one

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938971/how-do-i-get-the-output-from-database-executenonquery

Comment: @PaulF that answer is for Sql Server who has a Message parameter in the argument passed to InfoMessage. This parameter is missing in the EventArgs for MySql. It seems that there are only errors

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your suggestions and tips.. I was able to get the infomessage print on the console by using the errors property

```
 public static void OnInfoMessage(object sender, MySqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (MySqlError err in e.errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err.Code + ":" + err.Message);
        }

    }
```

and wherever you are opening a connection, just create the handler as mentioned in the comments

```
 conn.InfoMessage += new MySqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);
```

While it does not print how many errored out or skipped or inserted, it prints outs any columns truncated or incorrect.. etc exactly as you see on your mysql command line.