# Reading SSMS output message using pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have a list of MS SQL CREATE scripts and I am trying to automate the process of executing each of these scripts. As this CREATE scripts does not result any records, I would want my automation script to return the SSMS output message that looks like:
'Command executed successfully'

Can I read this output message using pyodbc?
Here is the sample code that I use to execute the script:

```
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=%s;Trusted_Connection=True;'% (db_conn_string))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really necessary to capture the "Command executed successfully" message because an exception will occur if the command is **not** executed successfully.

So your Python code can just `.execute` the statement, catch any exception that occurs, and proceed accordingly, e.g.,

```python
try:
    crsr.execute("DROP TABLE dbo.nonexistent")
    print("INFO: DROP TABLE succeeded.")
except pyodbc.ProgrammingError as err:
    error_code = err.args[0]
    if error_code == "42S02":  # [table] does not exist or you do not have permission
        print("INFO: DROP TABLE did not succeed.")
    else:
        raise  # re-raise unexpected exception
```

Comment: That helps a lot  ... Are there any packages available that captures console message, if pyodbc is not capable to do so?

Comment: @.Naran - I'd think that IronPython might be able to do it via the .NET `SqlClient` assembly, perhaps using the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1880471/2144390).

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.rowcount
```

Adding the above line to your code will return the row count for the last executed query.