# DBMS.OUTPUT_PUT.LINE in C# using MSSql

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

How do I put this DBMS.OUTPUT_PUT.LINE in a database, and is it also allowed to put it on listbox, datagridview or label?

example: [Time]: "NAME" has inserted a data.

Comment: I've got no idea what you are asking. Please explain in (much) more detail.

Comment: if you mean `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`; that's Oracle, not SQL Server; are you asking how to do something *like* `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in SQL Server? What has a db concept like `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` got to do with UI controls like listbox/datagridview?

Comment: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in Oracle and `PRINT` in Microsoft SQL Server return message text to the client. I guess you could consume those messages to display in a client UI but that's not commonly done. Use `SELECT` statements to return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get additional text data from an operation to be returned from a SQL operation similar to how `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` works, then [`PRINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql) allows that. Since you mention C#, you should note that to *consume* `PRINT` data you need to subscribe to the `SqlConnection.InfoMessage` event, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net).

However, in most cases it is more suitable / pragmatic to `SELECT` (perhaps via  [`OUTPUT`-clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql) in the case of `INSERT`/`DELETE` operations) something that informs the UI - perhaps the rows, perhaps the `@@ROWCOUNT`, perhaps the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. `PRINT` is usually a bad option for anything other than tool scripts.

Comment: Then, how could I display a report like this `"@Name" has inserted new data`?? Is there any options like that?

Comment: @Ian to whom are you trying to display it? if you want user X to see things that user Y has done: that isn't going to work - and I don't *think* it would work with `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` either. Usually, output data like this is specific to a single connection, which means user X would be able to see messages caused by commands on user X's connection, but: user X *already knows* the things that they've done, so it serves no purpose

Comment: I got enlightened, thank you