# Does a T-SQL PRINT statement get logged any where?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

Does a T-SQL PRINT statement get logged any where? Is there anyway I can see the results of the print statements after execution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880471/capture-stored-procedure-print-output-in-net

Comment: No, it doesn't get logged anywhere. It is sent to the client and if the client doesn't log it you've lost it